# How create inserted object use duktape?

Tags: c++, duktape

Have this code:

```
auto obj_idx = duk_push_object( ctx );

duk_push_string( ctx, "key" );
duk_push_string( ctx, "value" );
duk_put_prop( ctx, obj_idx );
duk_push_string( ctx, "key2" );
duk_push_string( ctx, "value" );
duk_put_prop( ctx, obj_idx );

duk_put_global_string( ctx, "obj" );
```

How insert new object in obj? No matter how hard I try to insert a nested object, it doesn’t work. Either crash or not inserted.

```
{
"key": "value",
"key2": "value",
"newObj": {
    "newKey": "value"
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the following code into the Duktape `hello` example and it produced the right result:

```
auto obj_idx = duk_push_object( ctx );

duk_push_string( ctx, "key" );
duk_push_string( ctx, "value" );
duk_put_prop( ctx, obj_idx );
duk_push_string( ctx, "key2" );
duk_push_string( ctx, "value" );
duk_put_prop( ctx, obj_idx );

auto nested_idx = duk_push_object(ctx);
duk_push_int(ctx, 2019);
duk_put_prop_string(ctx, nested_idx, "year");

duk_put_prop_string(ctx, obj_idx, "nested");

duk_put_global_string( ctx, "obj" );

duk_eval_string(ctx, "print(JSON.stringify(obj))");
```

The key thing to remember is that `duk_put_prop` and `duk_put_prop_string` take one value off the stack, while `duk_push_*` pushes a value on the stack.